# CSS Transform With Multiple Value

Tags: css, transform

Here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/04e4umjx/

```
@-webkit-keyframes circle{
    0% {
        -webkit-transform:translate(100px, 100px) rotate(0deg) translate(-100px, -100px) rotate(0deg);
        background-color:red;
    } 
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:translate(100px, 100px) rotate(360deg) translate(-100px, -100px) rotate(-360deg);
    }  
}
```

I guess this is simple, but I just don't understand why these keyframes create a circle path for the inner `div`.

And I am confused about the syntax of `transform` in this example.

What's the purpose to set `translate`&`rotate` value twice in one line?

Hope someone could help me.Thanks.

Comment: What is the wanted behavior

Comment: Read the CSS3 `transform` documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

Comment: Actually a good question, dosen't seem to be written out in the transform documentation at least not on moz